# Need to understand desc.workspaceType to use in conditionals

Tags: arcpy, workspace

I need to differentiate between two possible types of workspaces for an arcpy script. So I check the `workspaceType`:

```
rootWorkspace = raw_input('Geodatabase workspace to analyze: ')
desc = arcpy.Describe(rootWorkspace)
wsType = desc.workspaceType
print 'Workspace Type: {}'.format(wsType)
```

which seems to work fine and prints the correct type. But, if I try to then check the type (so I can, eventually, do different things depending on what it is):

```
if wsType is 'FileSystem': print 'file system'
if wsType is 'LocalDatabase': print 'gdb'
if wsType is 'RemoteDatabase': print 'sde'
else: print 'not reading this correctly'
```

I *always* get `not reading this correctly` (whether I'm inputting a directory or geodatabase).

According to Arc help about [Workspace properties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//000v00000037000000), `workspaceType` should be a string result (not an Object etc.), so I am confused why a string comparison isn't working.

Comment: Try using `elif` statements for the last 2 `if`'s.

Comment: Just tried that, and the problem persists.

Comment: By not using elif (instead of if) your code basically said "always print _not reading correctly_ unless wsType is RemoteDatabase".  See the [Python Flow Control help](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more details.

Comment: @RyanDalton that corrected a secondary problem, so thank you for pointing it out -- sloppy coding on my part, I generally know better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing "is" with "==" within the if statements.  When I tested it (python 2.6) I used a local FGDB:

```
if wsType is 'LocalDatabase':
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

The result here was False

```
if wsType =='LocalDatabase':
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

The result here was True

The first bit of code checks if the object identity of "wsType" and 'LocalDatabase' is the same, whereas the second bit of code checks if the strings "wsType" and 'LocalDatabase' are equal.

Comment: Chose this as the answer because you not only fixed it, you told me why I'm wrong so I won't make the same mistake again :)

Answer (score 3):

The following changes to your script should work for you:

```
import arcpy

rootWorkspace = r'C:\Users\OWNER\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'
desc = arcpy.Describe(rootWorkspace)
wsType = desc.workspaceType
print 'Workspace Type: {}'.format(wsType)

if wsType == 'FileSystem':
    print 'file system'
elif wsType == 'LocalDatabase':
    print 'gdb'
elif wsType == 'RemoteDatabase':
    print 'sde'
else:
    print 'not reading this correctly'
```

[image]